# Minimize Cost to Split Integer Arrays

Tags: dynamic-programming

There is a sorted integer array $a_1 \dots a_n$ and an integer $1 \leq k \leq n$, we need to figure out the minimized total cost to group this integer array into $k$ groups. The cost per group is mean($a_i \dots a_j$) for a group from $i$ to $j$. Give an algorithm in $O(nk)$. Group here means partitioning and there's no requirement for what element constraints inside each group.

I am currently trying to do dynamic programming for this but I am rather very lost on how to achieve $O(nk)$ time complexity. I have tried sorting the array and then pre-compute the segment sum but I still can't get the complexity down.

Comment: There are some details missing in your question. Do you want to [**partition**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set) the elements of the array? Meaning, can an element be in several groups? Do groups need to be made of consecutive elements? Please be precise.

Comment: @Nathaniel Sorry for the confusion, I have updated the question - group here means more like partitioning so one element can only be in one group - however, there may be multiple elements in the integer list that have exactly same value. There is no requirement for what elements have to be present in each group.

Comment: Are negative elements allowed in your array? Must each pair of consecutive elements in a group also be consecutive in the original array? What was your dynamic programming approach?

Comment: @ZiadIsmailiAlaoui Sorry for the confusion. The negative elements are not allowed in the array. There is no requirement for consecutive elements in a group must be consecutive in the original array but since the array is sorted I think the optimal way is to still treat consecutive in a group = consecutive in the original array. My current DP approach is that DP(i, j) gives the minimum cost for first i elements in the array with j partitions. The base case is DP(i, 1) = mean(1, i) and I am trying to do the bottom up from there.

Comment: May groups be empty ($i = j$)? I must be reading this wrong - what if I chose $k-1$ minimal groups from the little end?

Answer (score 0):

If the group elements do not need to be consecutive, then here is a simple approach:
Take the first element and place it in group 1; the second in group 2; and so on for the first $k$ elements. Then $(k+1)$-th element is placed in group 1, so on and so forth. In general $i$-th element in placed into group $((i-1) ~\text{mod}~ k + 1)$-th group. Each group would roughly cost about the overall mean of all elements.

Comment: From the wording of their post, it appears that elements must be grouped such that two consecutive elements in a group are also consecutive in the original array.

Comment: elements in a group are $k$ indices apart